# Azure Form Recognizer Label Tool Docker: Missing EULA=accept command line option. You must provide this to continue

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to run the Azure Forms Recognizer Label Tool in Azure Container instance.

I have followed the instructions given in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/deploy-form-recognizer-on-container-instances).

I was able to deploy the container image but when I try to start it, it terminates with the following message:

> Missing EULA=accept command line option. You must provide this to continue.

This quite surprising, because this option has been specified in my YAML file (see below).

What can I do to fix this?

My YAML file:

```
apiVersion: 2018-10-01
location: West Europe
name: renecognitiveservice
imageRegistryCredentials: # This is required when pulling a non-public image
  - server: mcr.microsoft.com
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
properties:
  containers:
  - name: xxxeamlabelingtool
    properties:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/custom-form/labeltool
      environmentVariables: # These env vars are required
        - name: eula
          value: accept
        - name: billing
          value: https://rk-formsrecognizer.cognitiveservices.azure.com/
        - name: apikey
          value: xxx
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 2 # Always refer to recommended minimal resources
          memoryInGb: 4 # Always refer to recommended minimal resources
      ports:
        - port: 5000
  osType: Linux
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
  ipAddress:
    type: Public
    ports:
    - protocol: tcp
      port: 5000
tags: null
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

Comment: It's confusing because EULA=accept should be in the command line, but not as an environment variable. I'm not familiar with the yaml syntax, so I don't know how to fix your issue, but hopefully that info helps.

Comment: I have the same issue. Trying to get it to work through the portal but no luck! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can run it with command:

```
"command": [
"./run.sh", "eula=accept"
],
```

Worked from the portal

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/46623

Comment: Can confirm that this works from the portal.  Just add "./run.sh", "eula=accept"
in the command field (tab: Advanced) while you create the container instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want to add in the Azure portal while creating the container instance. 
You will find this in the "Advanced" tab. 
Afterwards you can access the IP address of that instance to open the label-tool.

[image]

```
"./run.sh", "eula=accept"
```